# ASP.NET button_click not firing, after browser back button

Tags: asp.net, events, button

I have a ASPX Page that contains several user controls, which are loaded dynamically after user interaction.

On one of ascx I have a hidden button that is being clicked on some user actions (via button.click()), which works fine on 1st page load. 
But after the form is being submitted once, the other ascx is loaded. There if user clicks the back button and resubmits the 1st form (again via button.click()), button_clicked event on server does not fire again. Any thought?

Comment: Can you provide some code? First thought is that your control doesn't exits or browser back loads your page from cache.

Comment: the control wasn't loaded. Now i'm in a quest of detecting browser back button click and notifying server for some properties changes. Thax for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution - 2nd one is needed because of FireFox 3, which does preserve NO-CACHE directive.

```
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); 
  Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```